# Why does the following block in the browser until `lib.js` is loaded and evaluated?

Tags: javascript

What follows is a web server.

When `http://localhost:3000/` is visited the browser blocks until `lib.js` is loaded and evaluated.

Why?

Put another way: why does `app.js` not run in the browser before `lib.js` is?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

const page = `<html>
<head>
    <script>
        document.write('<scr' + 'ipt src="./lib.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
    </script>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
</head>
</html>`;

const libJs = `window.lib = function() { console.log('the library is loaded!'); };`;
const appJs = `window.lib();`;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(page)
});

app.get('/lib.js', (req, res) => setTimeout(() => res.send(libJs), 10000));

app.get('/app.js', (req, res) => res.send(appJs));

app.listen(3000, () => {});
```

**Edit:**

Replacing `page` with:

```
const page = `<html>
<head>
    <script>
        const el = document.createElement('script'); 
        el.src="./lib.js";
        document.currentScript.parentNode.insertBefore(el, document.currentScript);
    </script>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
</head>
</html>`;
```

Results in an error because inserting scripts in this latter way is async and dos not block evaluation of the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script element that loads `lib.js` appears in the DOM before the script element that loads `app.js`.

Since a script element might include a `document.write` statement, all script elements will block DOM parsing unless they are explicitly marked `defer` or `async`.

Comment: So this is peculiar to `document.write`? Because `const el = document.createElement('script'); el.src="./foo.js"; $('body).appendChild(el);` will not block.

Comment: @BenAston — That won't add the script at all. The body element doesn't exist yet.

Comment: How about if I changed the appending to `document.currentScript.parentNode.insertBefore(el, document.currentScript);`? This will not block and will result in `app.js` throwing an exception because `window.lib` is not defined.